# Shorten x-axis matplotlib but keep the predefined scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

I have defined the scale of the x-axis by using ax.set_xlim([0, 800])
but i want to shorten the length. How can i achieve the result of the second image.

[image: Scale from 0 to 800]

[image: Scale from 0 to 800 but shorter x-axis]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by explicitely reducing the figure width with [`figsize`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/figure_size_units.html)  compared to the height:

[image]

**Code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
x=[18,36,61,65,83]


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(1.5, 6))

ax.barh(y, x, color = 'olive')
ax.set_xlim([0, 100])
ax.set_xticks([0, 100])

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

**Notes:**

- align with `figsize=(width, height)` in inches (default), see link above on more options
- `ax.set_xlim([0, 100])` may be optional depending on your data / plot intention
- `ax.set_xticks([0, 100])` prevents interims ticks in case you increase the figsize width

  - if that's not intended just remove or adapt it